# googletest can't link to DUT

Tags: c++, c, linker, googletest

When I try to link the code that shall be tested to my tests I get `undefined refrence`.
When I use the same function in the same sourcefile there is no problem.
Here the linker error

```
g++  -o "VW_Test"  ./tests/scaleSignalTests.o  ./src/gtest-death-test.o ./src/gtest-filepath.o ./src/gtest-matchers.o ./src/gtest-port.o ./src/gtest-printers.o ./src/gtest-test-part.o ./src/gtest-typed-test.o ./src/gtest.o ./src/gtest_main.o  ./VirtualWall/PointCalc.o ./VirtualWall/checks.o ./VirtualWall/mathHelper.o   
./tests/scaleSignalTests.o: In function `TestBody':
C:\projects\VIRTUAL_WALL_TEST\Default/../tests/scaleSignalTests.cc:16: undefined reference to `multiplyInteger(int, int, int*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [VW_Test] Error 1
"make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

this is the test file

```
#include "PointCalc.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <math.h>


namespace {
class scaledIntTest : public ::testing::Test {
};
TEST_F(scaledIntTest, Multiplication)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(INT_FACTOR_TO_METER, 1000);
  int result = 0;

  // EXPECT_EQ(referencePoint, resultPoint);

  EXPECT_EQ(RTN_NO_ERR,
            multiplyInteger(INT_FACTOR_TO_METER * 1,
                            INT_FACTOR_TO_METER * 1,
                            &result));
  EXPECT_EQ(INT_FACTOR_TO_METER, result);
}


int foo(void)
{
  int result = 0;
  multiplyInteger(INT_FACTOR_TO_METER * 1, INT_FACTOR_TO_METER * 1, &result);
  return 1;
}
}
```

PointCalc.h

```
#ifndef POINT_CALC_H
#define POINT_CALC_H

#include "checks.h"
#define INT_FACTOR_TO_METER 1000

enum Return_codes {
  RTN_NO_ERR = 0,
  RTN_UNKNOWN,
  RTN_OUTPUT_ERR,
  RTN_MEMORY_ERR,
  RTN_INPUT_ERR,
  RTN_RANGE_ERR,
  RTN_VALIDATION_ERR
};

typedef struct sPoint {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} sPoint;

int multiplyInteger(int a, int b, int *result);
int addPoints(sPoint const *a, sPoint const *b, sPoint *sum);
int subPoints(sPoint *minuend, sPoint *subtrahend, sPoint *diff);
int mulPoints(int factor, sPoint *Point, sPoint *product);

#endif
```

PointCalc.c

```
#include "PointCalc.h"
#include "checks.h"
#include "mathHelper.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int multiplyInteger(int a, int b, int *result)
{

  if (!result) return RTN_OUTPUT_ERR;

  const long product = (long)a * b / INT_FACTOR_TO_METER;
  if (abs(product) < 32000) {
    *result = (int)product;
    return RTN_NO_ERR;
  }
  else {
    *result = sign(product) * 32000;
  }
  return RTN_RANGE_ERR;
}
```

I am at a loss what is going wrong here. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: May we look at PointCalc.cpp?

Comment: @S.M. added, but as it has other dependencies and compiled without error and warning and the function works in the other context I thought I'll omit it for brevity. I also shortend it down to the relevant function.

Comment: For your future success. What you thought was unimportant, was actually important. That's why [mcve]s are very desired on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the function in a C file, that has default `extern "C"` naming convention. The function in .h must be

```
extern "C" int multiplyInteger(int, int, int*);
```

Or the entire header file declarations must be enclosed in

```
#ifdef __cpluplus
extern "C" {
#endif
...

#ifdef __cpluplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Can you tell me why `foo` works though?

Comment: It does not work, the first error is shown. Or you have foo in another .c file, not in .cc file.

Comment: During my testing I commented out the googletest and just compiled the foo (it was not called though so maybe the linker discarded it). Also multiple calls of it were all reported. Anyhow it works now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, unused functions are not linked.